# Creating Content with createContentInContainer

Tags: python, plone

I've been trying to create content in my plone site using the Dexterity tool `createContentInContainer`.

I wrote a script that runs under my zopepy instance, and it accomplishes the following:

- Selects data from a SQL table.
- Creates a list of tuples that mirrors the custom content type defined in my product.

I know I'm extremely naive in my approach, but I've created a connection to the applications database by:

```
storage = FileStorage.FileStorage('.../var/filestorage/Data.fs')
db = DB(storage)
conn = db.open()
dbroot = conn.root()
```

I'm trying to create content by:

```
createContentInContainer(dbroot['Application']['myapp']['existingfolder'], portal_type, checkConstraints=False, content=item)
```

`portal_type` is previously set to my custom content type. `item` has been both the list of tuples passed to the content's interface (which throws a `Could not adapt` TypeError) as well as an unregistered adapter that inherits from the interface.

The interface for the type is registered in `mysite.Widget.xml` in `profiles/defualt/types`, but the script keeps throwing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/zopepy", line 345, in <module>
    execfile(__file__)
  File "importdex.py", line 105, in <module>
    createContentInContainer(dbroot['Application']['myapp']['existingfolder'], portal_type, checkConstraints=False, content=item)
  File "env/mysite/eggs/plone.dexterity-1.0-py2.7.egg/plone/dexterity/utils.py", line 149, in createContentInContainer
    content = createContent(portal_type, **kw)
  File "env/mysite/eggs/plone.dexterity-1.0-py2.7.egg/plone/dexterity/utils.py", line 105, in createContent
    fti = getUtility(IDexterityFTI, name=portal_type)
  File "env/mysite/eggs/zope.component-3.9.5-py2.7.egg/zope/component/_api.py", line 169, in getUtility
    raise ComponentLookupError(interface, name)
zope.component.interfaces.ComponentLookupError: (<InterfaceClass plone.dexterity.interfaces.IDexterityFTI>, 'mysite.Widget')
```

As I've mentioned, I know I'm extremely naive in my approach, and I probably deserve a slap on the hand. I apologize if I've presented my question in a confusing manner.

My questions are these:

- Can I instantiate `createContentInContainer` from zopepy? Is my rigged connection enough or does the script need to be run within the application to inherit stuff that Dexterity/FTI needs to accomplish what I'm asking?
- Do I need an adapter? The one i have inherits from `grok.Adapter` and passes the interface to `grok.provides` and `grok.context`, but should it declare properties based on the entirety of the content schema?
- The list of tuples is arbitrary. It just seemed like the thing to do given the structure of the ZODB. If I declare the schema of the content type as properties in a registered adapter, the data should be crafted to conform to attributes of an object (the adapter), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a little more context for your code to work. The Plone site acts as a local component registry, for example.

You are also better off using the `bin/instance run [scriptname]` command, it'll set up the database connection for you and pass the root object as `app` to your script. In that script, use the following boilerplate to get the rest of the scaffolding up:

```
import transaction
from zope.app.component.hooks import setSite
from Testing.makerequest import makerequest
from AccessControl.SecurityManagement import newSecurityManager

plone_site_id = 'Plone' # Adjust as needed.

app = makerequest(app)
site = app[plone_site_id]
setSite(site)
user = app.acl_users.getUser('admin').__of__(site.acl_users)
newSecurityManager(None, user)
```

With these in place you'll have everything you need to run your code. Don't forget to call `transaction.commit()` at the end. Your Plone site is reachable in the local variable `site`.

Comment: Can I buy you a beer? Thanks for your help, Martijn.

Comment: Oh, nice trick with setSite(site). I assume this just adds the methods related to the Plone site being a local component registry. Also, can you explain what \_\_of\_\_ does? And is it ok to use the system user instead? E.g. https://gist.github.com/3415599

Comment: @aclark: `__of__` is acquisition context wrapping. It *is* *a* system user (`app.acl_users.getUser('admin')`), and we rewrap it in the site's `acl_users` as if you logged in for the Plone site with it. Better to use the Plone site owner than the System user though.